# List view not Showing Proper Text

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

i want to create one list view in Hybrid Mobile Application. In every Cell i want to add data more than its width. i want to display only one line and remaining data will be hidden. In that one line i want to display only complete words, don't want any word to be truncated.

I am using ionic framework with Angular.

I have got one solution as well but that also truncate the words i.e. ellipsis.

Example: my requirement is
**In List View Cell the output should be** "Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new "
**not** "Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a ne".

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully there is an ionic css class to achieve what you need. Use the `item-text-wrap` class on your list item like so:

```
<div class="item item-text-wrap">
  This is a basic Card which contains an item that has wrapping text.
</div>
```

or

```
<ion-item class="item-text-wrap">
 {{textThatMayBeTooLong}}
</ion-item>
```

see [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#cards) for reference.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But it is not the answer of my question. I want to display only one line from a very big text content and when the display screen width get completed, then i want to show ellipsis, but on the same hand i don't want any word to be broken. i want to display only completed words and after that ellipsis(i.e. '...').

Comment: if you had a fiddle we could test it. try to add the css to your div with the text `word-wrap: normal;`